# Why Ubuntu installation on Hyper-V has internet by default?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, hyper-v

I just installed latest version of `Ubuntu 20.04` on my `Hyper-V` of my `Windows -10` and noticed that I can right away connect to the internet through its default browser `FireFox`. I thought I would have to create an `external Virtuyal switch` for it to connect to internet. **Question**: Why the `Ubuntu` is by default connecting to the internet and how this functionality can be disabled so I have control on its internet connection whenever I need it?

Comment: When the virtual machine was created, you likely used a wizard, and by default, the required virtual adapter was used.

Comment: On my Hyper-V machine, internet to guest is ON by default and modern guests look for Wired Internet (which is what this is for virtual machines). Perhaps build a little program in Ubuntu to turn Internet  OFF and then ON again.